# A Database Error Occurred - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I got this error :

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/soheil/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

but when I add below code inside `database.php` it prints ok :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($db['default']);
echo '</pre>';

echo 'Connecting to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
$dbh=mysql_connect
(
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . ' Line: ' .__LINE__);
```

---

my config :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'soheil',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you put your `username` on database? It maybe `root` user

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'soheil',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Hope this help.